# How do you fetch files from Google cloud storage bucket after a certain file is fetched using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

Suppose in my Google Cloud storage bucket there are approx 10k files and while fetching these using python I set a limit as `max_results=100`. I save the timestamp and the name of the last file using `blob.updated` and `blob.name`.
How do I make sure that the next time my python program is run it would fetch the files after the 100th file(which has already been saved). So basically fetching the files after `max_results=100` ie from `max_results=101`

I have gone through the documentation and I couldn't find anything relevant to what I want to do. I am also aware of the fact that max_results parameter would give results till the number it has been called, in my case it is 100.
here is the code:

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = 'json_file.json'
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(max_results=100)
last_file_timestamp = list()
name_list = list()
for blob in blobs:
    name_list.append(blob.name)
    last_file_timestamp.append(blob.updated)
print(name_list)
print(last_file_timestamp)
```

To put it in simple terms - How do I ensure that the second time my python script is executed, it would fetch the files from bucket after 100 files.? Is there a way? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform a query to Google API, you have a set of result and a next page token in you have more results. In this case, use this token and request the next page to the API.

Here an example based on your code

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = 'json_file.json'
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

#First 100 results
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(max_results=100)
for blob in blobs:
    print(blob.name)

#Next 100 results
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(page_token=blobs.next_page_token,max_results=100)
for blob in blobs:
    print(blob.name)
```

Comment: That was just what I wanted to get. You've been of great help. Thanks Guillaume !!